# Difference unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 vs system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0

Tags: selinux

What's the difference in these two contexts SELINUX

`unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0` vs `system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0`

Comment: The first field is the SE LInux user. The first context has the `unconfined_u` user (which is the default), the second context has the `system_u` context. The third field is the type. The first context has type `admin_home_t`, the second context has type `systemd_unit_file_t`.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 Could you please elaborate on difference in admin_home_t vs systemd_unit_file_t, Can we use systemctl commands with file which has admin_home_t type selinux context ?

Comment: I cannot tell, because that depends on what SE Linux rules you are using. Please specify what Operating System you are using and which version.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 I'm using RHEL8.2, the SE Linux rules should be default since I've not changed them explicitly.